# Cancel the 'onclick' JS when link is clicked

Tags: javascript, onclick, click, dom-events

I have the link `<a href="#" onclick="foo(); return false;">Mylink</a>`. Now I want when user clicks the link and a condition is true to not execute the `foo` function, but do something else. Is there a way to achieve this (desirable with jQuery or clean Javascript)?

Comment: Remove the `onclick` handler? `$('a').removeAttr('onclick');`? But why do you have the onclick handler when you don't want it?

Comment: `onclick="somethingElse(); return false;"`?

Comment: @putvande, thx. But is there a way to cancel it when a condition is true? Let's say if the tag `a` has class `inactive` then don't execute `foo`.

Comment: @SpartakusMd Do you want to do like this... `<a href="#" onclick="javascript:if(1==1){callOtherFunction();}else{foo();} return false;">Mylink</a>`

Comment: I would put that in the function itself. Check for that class, or whatever you want to check on and return false.

Comment: @putvande, I can't edit the function `foo`.

Comment: @SpartakusMd, In this case change the `foo` function with anather one that checks the condition and call you function.

Comment: Why can't you change that function?

Comment: this is really simple if you were not using inline event handlers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.removeEventListener

Comment: @putvande, I can, but it is not desired to do this, it is a part of the "framework".

Comment: http://pastebin.com/hvi9fbnz example without inline event handlers

Comment: Thank you all. I'll accept the CoalaArmy's anwer probably or the one of rlemon. I'll think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can change the `foo` function with another one that checks the condition and call your function.
- Or you can follow the rlemon's anwer and use EventListeners

  link.addEventListener('click', function linkHandler() { 
          foo();
          this.removeEventListner('click', linkHandler, false);
      }, false);

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to do like this... or somthing else?

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:if(1==1){callOtherFunction();}else{foo();} return false;">Mylink</a>
```